# Adding action to a UIButton in ios sdk

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add a button to a view  programmatically and i am using the following code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 20, 80, 70)];
[self addButton:button];
```

according to me code looks right but i am getting error "Unknown action click"

addbutton and click is the method of the same class
and i am adding the buttons in my constructor

what's the problem with the click method? is there any syntax error!

Comment: Show your `click:` method.

Comment: - (void)click{
    NSLog(@"Button Clicked");
}

Comment: you add click method with id like click:(id)sender

Comment: post your click: method and error log.

Comment: hi jsut remove colon in click: it will work

Comment: No, no, not again! Y U NO read an Objective-C tutorial before attempting to write an OS in Objective-C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a method named `click` but your are telling your button that the method is named `click:`. Notice the difference (the colon).

Change the `@selector` to `@seletor(click)` so it matches the actual method name.

Another option is to leave the `@selector` as-is but update your `click` method to `click:`:

```
- (void)click:(UIButton *)button {
    // button was tapped - do something
}
```

Comment: its not working  same error...i have seen in other stackoverflow question about the colon   i think its syntax for adding action but i am not sure

Comment: other places are able to call the function so there is no problem with function

Comment: i tried both (change the function name and change the selector) but getting same error.....

Comment: No, you must only make one of the changes. Either change the selector or change the method, not both.

Answer (score 1):

A sample how to add a action to a button ....

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithTypeRoundRect];  
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
button.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,100,50);
//Do some more Configuration of the button like title.. Look at UIButton Class Reference
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

SomeTimes you see a small colon(:) after the method name in the selector something like this @selector(myMethod:)
which means this method takes some argument. the colon plays no role in the name of the method. if you are not sending any argument to the function then don't put colon after the name of the function.....
In addtarget option you can see that self is specified because self contains myMethod function. Here you are supposed to specify the reference of that object which contains your Method.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 - (void)click:(id)sender{ NSLog(@"Button Clicked"); }
```

or change action click: to click

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(click) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

hi just simply try this `-(void)click { // do what ever }` i.e just remove colon in @selector(click:) hope it will work

Comment: why u add two answers to same question